# java class invoking/calling jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, constructor

creating a webserver in netbeans with I have 3 files index.jsp, response.jsp and client.java.
the idea is to create a temperature converter, but only takes the input and not doing the calculator job.
please any help!?

index.jsp

```
<form name="Input Form" id="ftemp" action="response.jsp">
            <input type="text" name="temp" />
            <select name="conv1">
                <option>Celsius</option>
                <option>Fahrenheit</option>
            </select>
            <select name="conv2">
                <option>Fahrenheit</option>
                <option>Celsius</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
```

response.jsp

```
<body>

        <h1>your list is in order</h1>
        <jsp:useBean id="sortbean" scope="session" class="sortclient.SortClient" />
        <jsp:setProperty name="sortbean" property="input" />          
        <jsp:setProperty name="sortbean" property="cel"  />
        <jsp:setProperty name="sortbean" property="fahr" />
        <jsp:getProperty name="sortbean" property="input" />
    </body>
```

client.java

```
public class SortClient {

    private String input;   
    double cel = 0;
    double fahr = 0;

        public SortClient (){
            input = null;
        }

    public String getInput() {

    try{
        String key = getKey();
        input = mergeSort (input,key);
        double tempCelsius = input.nextDouble();
        double tempFahrenheit = input.nextDouble();

        return input;
    }catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex); //we would log this
            return "That is not a valid list";
        }
    }



    public void setInput(String input) {
        this.input = input;

    }

   public double toCelsius( double tempFahrenheit )
    { 
        return ((5.0 / 9.0) * ( tempFahrenheit - 32 ));

    }

   public double toFahrenheit( double tempCelsius )
    { 
        return (tempCelsius * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32;

    }


    private static String mergeSort(java.lang.String input, java.lang.String userKey) {
        org.tempuri.Service service = new org.tempuri.Service();
        org.tempuri.IService port = service.getBasicHttpBindingIService();
        return port.mergeSort(input, userKey);
    }

    private static String getKey() {
        org.tempuri.Service service = new org.tempuri.Service();
        org.tempuri.IService port = service.getBasicHttpBindingIService();
        return port.getKey();
    }
```

Comment: You need to forward the request to the model logic from the JSP, then forward to a response page. Look up "Model-View-Controller" (MVC), and in particular the old Sun "Model 2" architecture. I found these links after a minute or three of searching:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSP_model_2_architecture
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076557/java-web-development/understanding-javaserver-pages-model-2-architecture.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple problems in your code. Here are some suggestions:

1. Match the input names in `index.html` and `SortClient.java` to avoid confusion and simplify property assignments
2. Create setter and getter for all fields or else `jsp:setProperty` and `jsp:getProperty` won't work
3. Pay attention on your data types: `String` doesn't have `nextDouble()`. If you haven't please use IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans, Intellij .etc) assistance.
4. Remove unnecessary libraries and code eg. `org.tempuri.*`

Here are codes implementing suggestions above:

**index.jsp**

```
  <form name="Input Form" id="ftemp" action="response.jsp">
    <input type="text" name="temp" />
    <select name="conv1">
      <option>Celsius</option>
      <option>Fahrenheit</option>
    </select>
    <select name="conv2">
      <option>Fahrenheit</option>
      <option>Celsius</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

**response.jsp**

```
<h1>your list is in order</h1>
<jsp:useBean id="sortbean" scope="session" class="sortclient.SortClient" />
<jsp:setProperty name="sortbean" property="*" />
Input: <jsp:getProperty name="sortbean" property="temp" /><br>
Conv1: <jsp:getProperty name="sortbean" property="conv1" /><br>
Conv2: <jsp:getProperty name="sortbean" property="conv2" /><br>
Result: <jsp:getProperty name="sortbean" property="result" />
```

**SortClient.java**

```
package sortclient;

public class SortClient {
    private String temp;
    private String conv1;
    private String conv2;
    private Double result;

    public String getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }

    public void setTemp(String temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public String getConv1() {
        return conv1;
    }

    public void setConv1(String conv1) {
        this.conv1 = conv1;
    }

    public String getConv2() {
        return conv2;
    }

    public void setConv2(String conv2) {
        this.conv2 = conv2;
    }

    public Double getResult() {
        result = Double.parseDouble(temp);
        if (conv1.equalsIgnoreCase(conv2)) {
            return result;
        } else if (conv2.equalsIgnoreCase("Celsius")) {
            return toCelsius(result);
        } else if (conv2.equalsIgnoreCase("Fahrenheit")) {
            return toFahrenheit(result);
        }
        return 0.0;
    }

    public double toCelsius(double tempFahrenheit )
    {
        return ((5.0 / 9.0) * ( tempFahrenheit - 32 ));

    }

    public double toFahrenheit( double tempCelsius )
    {
        return (tempCelsius * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32;

    }

}
```

Refer to [this tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps.html) for detailed guide.

As other have suggested, this approach is actually considered obsolete as it's tightly coupled and not maintainable on big scale. So I'd also suggest you to learn MVC pattern as from tutorial such as:

http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html
http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/

Comment: thank you for your help! so I haven't learned about parse yet and my teacher was telling me to use 3 set and 1 getters for it!?

Comment: 3 setters (`temp`, `conv1`, `conv2`) and 1 getter (`result`) may also work if you don't display the inputs in the `response.jsp` (by calling `jsp:getProperty`)